Как посмотреть summary() для нейросети?
Имея обученную нейросеть, сохраненную в HDF5 формате, я могу загрузить ее и посмотреть параметры нейросети:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model, Sequential, load_model

my_model = keras.models.load_model('/content/my_checkpoint.h5')
my_model.summary()

также я могу сохранить модель целиком в директорию:
model.save('path/to/dir/for/model/')

и модель тогда будет представлять набор файлов:

я также могу загрузить модель из этой директории и посмотреть summary()
model_2 = keras.models.load_model('path/to/dir/for/model/')
model_2.summary()

Однако, если модель сохранена в виде весов в формате Checkpoint и представляет собой набор файлов, подобно этому:

Как я могу загрузить эту модель и посмотреть summary() для нее ?
